# Vertically centered 100% height div doesn't reach the the top in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Here is the code

```
<style>
.test{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  background:blue;
}
</style>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like. I tested this in Chrome and IE and the gap doesn't appear.

[image]

The gap remains if I set the height to `100%` `100vh` or the absolute height in pixels. I am using Firefox 40 so the browser is up to date.

Also, for anyone wondering why you would center a div that has a height of 100% it is so that it will center no matter the orientation of the screen.

**EDIT**
For all those suggesting setting `margin:0` it unfortunately doesn't fix the problem

**Clarification of the problem.**

Apparently this is rounding error in the rendering engine. Because if you change the height of the window the gap appears and disappears. Chrome seems to show a slight gap but it is almost indistinguishable. To see the problem try changing the frame height in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m4yqoq4w/. I assume this also means there is no easy way to fix the problem.

Comment: And there's no margins and paddings in body?

Comment: mostly because of the body margins or padding. See in iframe your code: http://jsfiddle.net/m4yqoq4w/

Comment: But shouldn't the absolute position ignore the body margin?

Comment: Based on the css you gave us, this problem doesn't occur on my updated version of firefox on mac

Comment: @coozin perhaps it is a bug in the Windows version of Firefox

Comment: Are you struggling with the 1px margin at the top or the few pixels on the left?

Comment: @briand The 1px at the top

Comment: I thought so. It would be great if you would produce a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.com so that we can play with the problem and look for a solution with you. Also your **EDIT** comes off as very aggressive; you might consider rephrasing it to clarify your issue and show your appreciation for the help (possibly something to the effect of "Thank you so much to everyone who is working on this with me. Unfortunately, `margin:0` doesn't remove the 1px margin at the top that I'm trying to get rid of")

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0;` to the body

Before: http://jsfiddle.net/m4yqoq4w/
After: http://jsfiddle.net/2umLokj4/

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
 body{
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce the "top" property value as below, you will never get the gap

`top:49%;`